# Unable to set font family to "Arial Black" via JavaScript in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, fonts

I am unable to set a font-family with a name containing a space **via JavaScript** in Firefox, while it works in Chrome.

### HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>First item</li>
    <li>Second item</li>
    <li>Third item</li>
</ul>
```

### JavaScript

```
window.document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1].style.fontFamily = '"arial black", consolas';
```

Here is a **[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4Lnkj34z/)**

In Firefox the first family name gets ignored, apparently because the string is interpreted as `""arial black", consolas"`. So Firefox displays the text in Consolas. But Chrome gets it right...

Is there a way around this behaviour?

**Edit**

### Environment :

- Intel NUC with 16 GB RAM, i7
- Windows 8.1 Pro
- 64-bits
- French

Comment: worked on firefox 43, 44, 45 for me on mac. what operating system?

Comment: Please explain downvote

Comment: What about this? https://jsfiddle.net/eghns9rv/

Comment: @olivier, your solution only seems to work because of the Helvetica declaration...

Comment: @Sébastien found this: http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/2234616

Comment: but i guess this is not the problem

Comment: maybe you can try the stackoverflow chat and look there if somebody can help you

Answer (score 1):

Arial Black is the 900 weight of the Arial family. Try this:

CSS:

```
font-family:"Arial Black", Gadget, Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: 900;
```

JavaScript:

```
window.document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1].style.fontFamily = '"Arial Black", Gadget, Arial, sans-serif;';
window.document.getElementsByTagName('li')[1].style.fontWeight = "900";
```

Comment: This is really not my question, I don't want to do it in CSS, I need to do it in JavaScript.

Comment: There you go! :-) @Sébastien

Comment: I still get the same result in Chrome (works) and Firefox (fails)

Comment: That is weird. It works for my firefox 45 on Mac, as well as my Windows.

Comment: The link from @OleReidarHolm works for me as well in chrome (latest), safari and firefox

Answer (score 0):

I think you problem is because you wrote `arial black` instead of `Arial Black`

Css fonts can be case sensitive.

Comment: Did you _test_ this supposition in any way, or is this really a _guess_ rather than an answer?  When answers on SO start with "I think that..." or "I guess that..." they are nearly always bad answers, and someone (not me) is very likely to downvote.

Comment: Ok, thank you  @StephenP it's really a guess... I comment next time.